# How can you prevent X-Forwarded-For spoofing on haproxy?

Tags: ip, haproxy

Is there a way to prevent the X-Forwarded-For from being spoofed in haproxy?

i.e. Can I rename that header to something else? Or is there another way to forward on the correct IP address of the client?

Comment: I'm not really sure that I understand the answer to that question. If you delete the X-Forwarded-For header, how can you get the client's IP address? Surely the X-Forwarded-For won't exist then?

Comment: The answer states that haproxy removes any such header the client sends, and inserts its own, when the given configuration is used.